# Delegate send on click submit button (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say we have

```
$submitButton.click(function(e){
    doSomething(e);
    return false;
});
```

Where `$submitButton` is the jQuery object of the submit button of a form. Say `doSomething` is an async method with an AJAX call.

If I `return true` then the form is submitted before `doSomething` ends, so I want to `return false` and then once `doSomething` ends the AJAX, in the success callback, I want to actually submit the form.

Is this possible using just `e`? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$submitButton.click(function(e){
    //make doSomething return a promise that you can chain off of
    doSomething(e).then(function(){
        //submit the parent form
        $submitButton.closest('form').trigger('submit');
    });

    //cancel the click and wait for the ajax to finish
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It seems that by invoking `e.target.click()` I don't get the form submitted but the button clicked, which just runs the same callback over and over again (as it returns false). I guess I must find the form via `e.target` and submit it directly, or passing by a flag (not cool).

Comment: `e.target.click()` shouldn't be causing that callback to happen again.

Comment: Woah, yeah, I don't remember it doing that behavior, but yeah it is.  Changed it to target the parent form and submit it.  @CarlosNavarroAstiasarán